# The expression "have been here."

Tags: expressions

> I've been here for more than sixty years.

I want to make sure if the expression "have been here for...." imply that he didn't live here originally, and he moved here 60 years ago.

I mean if a person was  born and grew up in a place, can he use the expression "I have been here for...."

Comment: Note that it's fine to say things like ***I have been here all my life***. Idiomatically, if you say you've been in some location / condition ***for*** some specified length of time, there would often be an implication that you were somewhere else or in some other condition ***before*** that, but not necessarily.

Comment: Your comment can very well make an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not imply that.  He might also use the phrase if he was born there.

Interestingly, adding a colloquial "now" on the end subtly shifts the meaning to imply what you want:  "I've been here for over sixty years, now..." is indeed something that someone "originally" from the area would tend to not say.